# SQL SELECT is selecting rows that do not match the query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php mysql_query() to select rows from my SQL Database but for some reason it is selecting rows that do not match the query. For example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID='153'")
```

This will return the row who has an ID of 153

but so will:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID='153c'")
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: implicit conversion of numeric string data to numeric....

Comment: mysql_query(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID='153c'")  you are missing one of the double qoutes in this line of code

Comment: The missing quote was just a mistake in typing the question, but @MitchWheat was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the issue is comparing a string value to an integer value.  Your expression is:

```
WHERE ID = '153' and
WHERE ID = '153a'
```

You can imagine the MySQL engine describing what it does as: "`id` is an integer column.  So, I need to compare it to an integer value.  Oh, the right side is a string, so I will convert the right hand side to an integer."

The way that MySQL converts values to a number from a string could be called "silent conversion".  It converts the longest leading number that it finds, and then stops.  If there is no leading number (say `'a123'`), then the value is `0`.  There is no error produced.

If you really want to confuse yourself, consider the following:

```
select (case when 123 = '123e' then 1 else 0 end),
       (case when 123 = '123e3' then 1 else 0 end),
       (case when 123 = '123a' then 1 else 0 end),
       (case when 123 = '123a3' then 1 else 0 end)
```

This returns:  true, false, true, and true.  Why is the second one false, but the others true?  Well, '123e3' is interpreted as scientific notation, so the value becomes 123,000.  For all the others, the conversion stops at the first alphabetic character.

As mentioned in the other answers, the obvious fix is to drop the single quotes on the constant.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing the ID value as a String? This would most likely be your issue.  Try passing the following query instead:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID= 153")
```

This way, the ID value being searched for is an int (or any other primitive the ID column is set to).  This should restrict the IDs properly.  In addition, if you are creating IDs with numbers, it's best practice to use distinct ints only and not strings.